# How to rank text-boxes values?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I have 5 TextBoxes in my form. I want to rank them in other text-boxes by pressing a button.

Above 5 text-boxes takes values every time different.

I have tried the below mentioned codes but not works. I want to show for high-value TextBox rank "1" so low value "2" and so on.

Names of new TextBoxes: `textbox25`, `textbox24`, `textbox23`, `textbox22`, `textbox21`.

Names of TextBoxes which have value for ranking already mentioned in the following code.

```vb
Dim i As String() = New String() {Val(TextBox20.Text), Val(TextBox19.Text),
                                      Val(TextBox18.Text), Val(TextBox17.Text),
                                      Val(TextBox16.Text)}
Dim lastScore As Integer
Dim lastScorePosition As Integer
Dim position As Integer = 1

For Each i1 In i
    If Val(lastScore) <> Val(i1) Then
        TextBox25.Text = (position)
        lastScorePosition = position
        lastScore = Val(i1)
    Else
        TextBox25.Text = (lastScorePosition & ",")
    End If
    position += 1
Next
```

No result in new text-boxes.

[image: Information about textboxes and button]

Comment: `I have tried below mentioned codes but not works`  What doesn't work?  Errors?  What value are you getting versus what are you expecting?  You have to explain things in greater detail in order for us to help you.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will make your errors obvious. If you still have problems after fixing the code post a new question with the new code.

Comment: `Val()` returns a `Double`... so why an array of `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the new image. Try this:

```vb
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of TextBox, TextBox) From
    {
    {txtMerit1, txtMerit1Rank},
    {txtMerit2, txtMerit2Rank},
    {txtMerit3, txtMerit3Rank},
    {txtMerit4, txtMerit4Rank},
    {txtMerit5, txtMerit5Rank}
    }

Dim i As Integer = 1

For Each kvp In dic.OrderByDescending(Function(a) Convert.ToSingle(a.Key.Text))
    kvp.Value.Text = i
    i += 1
Next
```

This will create a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) that holds each Merit and its rank text boxes as [KeyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.8) pairs. Then, will descending order the entries according to the values of the merits text boxes, and finally, will show the rank in the connected rank text boxes.

Here is a quick demo:

[image]

Hope it works this time.

Good luck.

Comment: more details about my question is in the newly uploaded photo. this code is ok, but my problem, not solved. also i'm new i program writing, please give me detiled code. thanks

Comment: Please check the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Explanations and comments in-line.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    'Don't change to a number with Val when you want an array of String
    Dim StringArray As String() = {TextBox20.Text, TextBox19.Text,
                              TextBox18.Text, TextBox17.Text,
                              TextBox16.Text}
    'Change the Strings to Integers with Linq
    Dim IntegerArray As Integer() = (From i In StringArray
                                     Select CInt(i)).ToArray
    '.Sort puts the array in numerical order 
    Array.Sort(IntegerArray)
    'The highest number will be the last number in the array
    TextBox25.Text = IntegerArray(IntegerArray.Length - 1).ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim boxes As TextBox() = New TextBox() {TextBox20, TextBox19, TextBox18, TextBox17, TextBox16.Text}
Dim ordered = boxes.OrderBy(Function(box) Val(box.Text))
TextBox25.Text = String.Join(",", ordered.Select(Function(box) box.Text))
```